# Backbone Model.fetch() - how does it take care of duplicates

Tags: backbone.js

As per the  [backbone js](https://backbonejs.org/) documentation, model.fetch() merges current model's state  with server if different exists in the attributes.

Question 1: Is there a way I can tell backbone to overwrite the attribute in the server's model with the local model ?

Question 2: How can I view all the attributes in a model using Chrome Dev Tools?

Thank you

Comment: May I suggest you edit your question title so it can reflect your questions?

Answer (score 0):

1: You can use the [save](https://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) method.

2: You can see modal attributes with Chrome Developer Tools like so:

[image: How to see modal attributes with Chrome Developer Tools]